# SOAP request from php is not working giving error: HTTP-Internal Server Error

Tags: php, soap

i am using code below to make SOAP request on a server. SOAP request is successfully login, but after that function "CreateDocumentFromFile" is not working using parameters i have given.

```
    $wsdl = "WSDL url";
    $soapClient = new SoapClient($wsdl);

    try {
        $loginStat = $soapClient->login($credential);
    } catch (SoapFault $fault) {
        print("ERROR: ".$fault->faultcode."-".$fault->faultstring);
    }
$options = array(
        'p' => array(
            'Document' => array(
                 'Subject' => 'TEST WS 1',
                 'Note' => 'TEST WS 1',
                 'BusinessUnitID' => '1',
                 'SourceID' => '3',
                 'CategoryID' => '44',
                 'TitolarioID' => '628',
                 'FascicleID' => '27',
                 'TypeID' => '9',
                 'SenderUORs' => '8',
                 'RecipientUORs' => '8',
                 'ShowCase' => '0',
                 'IsSubscribed' => '0',
                 'Inventory' => '0',
                 'IsPublic' => '0'
            ),
            'ProtocolDocument' => '1',
            'Data' => 'dGVzdERvY1A=',
            'FileName' => 'pdafhjjd_doc3.txt',
            'FileType' => '11',
            'IsSigned' => '0',
            'SignDate' => '04/02/2019',
            'CheckOriginality' => '0'
        )
    );
try {
        $saveFile = $soapClient->CreateDocumentFromFile($options);
    } catch (SoapFault $fault) {
        print("ERROR: ".$fault->faultcode."-".$fault->faultstring);
    }
```

Comment: Are you getting any errors?

Comment: what are you getting in catch block?

Comment: I suggest using `SoapVar` instances instead of an array. Use the soap client internal function `__getTypes()` to see, what kind of complex types (structs) and simple types are in need and what the namespace declarations are. Soap and php are not that easy, as it seems.

Comment: Double check all variables(parameters) used to match the soap structure in the wsdl file. All variables are case sensitive. Soap Endpoints can throw an internal server error for any mismatched data